# PrimeFaces MenuItem Right to left display

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I've added a menu in top right corner and sub menu goes right side and it is entirely invisible.

[image: Submenu Right to left]

Can any one advice how to get this submenu to left side. I do not require RTL feature here.

Code sample as follows :

```
<p:menubar id="menubar" style=" border: none;background : threedface;">
  <p:submenu icon="appmenu" >
  <p:submenu label="Account" >
  <p:menuitem value="Account View">
   <f:param name="menu" value="Account"/>
  </p:menuitem>
  <p:menuitem value="Transfer" />
  <p:menuitem value="Credit note" />
  <p:menuitem value="Debit note"/>
  </p:submenu>
   ...
</p:menubar>
```

Answer (score 1):

This property will get the menu blocks to appear on the left side.But this will cause all the menus to be on the left side.

```
.ui-menu-child {
  left: -200px !important;
}
```

You would need to play around a bit to get exactly what you need.

Comment: sorry, it doesn't help

Comment: It doesn't help how ? Works fine for me. I have tried it at my end.